# biblatex: \parencite in note field prints spurious ; with authoryear-icomp style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a book and two of its translation in my bibliography list. Each book has a note that cites the other translation. For that, I use a `\parencite` command in the `note` field.

If I use the `authoryear-icomp` style a spurious `;` appears in the notes; as shown in the image. With the `authoryear` style this is not happenning.

[image]

What should I do to remove the unwanted `;`?

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}


\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book {b11,
     MRKEY = {MR0113788},
    AUTHOR = {Bourbaki, Nicolas},
     TITLE = {Éléments d'histoire des mathématiques},
    SERIES = {Histoire de la Pensée, IV},
 PUBLISHER = {Hermann, Paris},
      YEAR = {1960},
     PAGES = {277},
   MRCLASS = {01.00},
  MRNUMBER = {0113788},
MRREVIEWER = {C. J. Scriba},
      note = {Também disponivel em Inglês em \parencite{b11en} e Espanhol em \parencite{b11es}},
}
%%%%
@book {b11en,
    AUTHOR = {Bourbaki, Nicolas},
     title = {Elements of the History of Mathematics},
      isbn = {9783540647676},
      lccn = {98039221},
       url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-61693-8},
      year = {1998},
     PAGES = {301},
 publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
   address = {Berlin Heidelberg},
      note = {Traduzido por J. Meldrum do original em Francês \parencite{b11}, também disponivel em Espanhol em \parencite{b11es}},
}
%%%%

@book {b11es,
    AUTHOR = {Bourbaki, Nicolas},
     title = {Elementos de historia de las mathemáticas},
      isbn = {84-206-2018-1},
      year = {1972},
     PAGES = {401},
 publisher = {Alianza Editorial},
   address = {Madrid},
      note = {Traduzido por Jesús Hernández do original em Francês \parencite{b11}, também disponivel em Inglês em \parencite{b11en}},
}
%%%%
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parencite{b11}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex`'s punctuation tracker is confused by this sort of 'nesting'. You only see this with `authoryear-icomp`, because that style has to rely more on the tracker than `authoryear`.

In particular `authoryear-icomp`'s `\cite` commands usually leave the punctuation buffer non-empty to handle `\multicitedelim` and `\compcitedelim` properly (see also my answer to [biblatex: \DeclareCiteCommand adds semicolon between \printfield and \printnames, but only sometimes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435162/35864)). This is not a problem in the usual context because `\cite` clears the punctuation buffer before it does its work. If `\cite` is called in a bibliography context, however, it does not clear the buffer to avoid messing with the surrounding punctuation.

With

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\blx@citecmdinit{%
  \blx@leavevmode@cite
  \blx@initunit}
\makeatother
```

you can slightly alter the behaviour of `\cite` commands in the bibliography so that they don't believe they printed something already.

If you want to be more careful, define a special command to prefix the offending `\parencite`s

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mkbibcitesafe}{\blx@initunit}
\makeatother
```

and use that in the `note`

```
note = {Traduzido por Jesús Hernández do original em Francês \parencite{b11},
        também disponivel em Inglês em \makebibcitesafe\parencite{b11en}},
```

---

You may want to have a look at the `related` functionality that `biblatex` offers to link several bibliography entries. This is usually preferable to using `\cite` commands in `.bib` fields, where things could go wrong (as demonstrated here).