# biblatex: remove full stop after report type

Tags: biblatex, type

I am new to biblatex, and need to make a bibliography entry for reports that is a modified version of harvard. I have been able to meet the requirements so far as shown below.

> World Economic Forum (2020) The Future of Jobs Report 2020. [pdf]. Geneva:
> World Economic Forum. Available at: http://www3.weforum.org/docs/WEF_Future_of_Jobs_2020.pdf [Accessed 19 December 2020].

However, I need still need to remove the fullstop after "[pdf]" in order for the style to be correct and am unsure how to do so.

`main-bib.bib`

```
@report{WEF:2020,
author = {{World Economic Forum}},
title = {The Future of Jobs Report 2020},
type = {pdf},
institution = {World Economic Forum},
year = {2020},
location = {Geneva},
url = {http://www3.weforum.org/docs/WEF_Future_of_Jobs_2020.pdf},
urldate = {2020-12-19},
}
```

Main file:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    style=ext-authoryear,
    uniquename=init,
    articlein=false,
    dateabbrev=false,
    maxcitenames=1,
    maxbibnames=99,
    giveninits,
    backend=biber
    ]{biblatex}
    
%formats report type into square brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{type}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
    
\addbibresource{main-bib.bib}
\begin{document}
Citing: \cite{WEF:2020}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with two changes in the  `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}`,

From

```
\printfield{type}%
\setunit*{\addspace}%
```

to

```
\printfield[brackets]{type}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
\printunit*{\addspace}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Try this code

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    style=ext-authoryear,
    uniquename=init,
    articlein=false,
    dateabbrev=false,
    maxcitenames=1,
    maxbibnames=99,
    giveninits,
    backend=biber
    ]{biblatex}
    
%formats report type into square brackets
%\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{type}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit
    \printlist{language}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield[brackets]{type}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \printunit*{\addspace}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \printfield{number}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{version}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{pagetotal}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isrn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
        \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}
    
\addbibresource{main-bib.bib}
\begin{document}
Citing: \cite{WEF:2020}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: dot]

You already had figured out the first, but I thought it was better to put the two together.

This is the explanation of the second part, from `biblatex` manual *sec 4.7.1*

> \setunit{⟨punctuation⟩} \setunit*{⟨punctuation⟩}
>
> The \setunit command is similar to \newunit except that it uses
> ⟨punctuation⟩ instead of \newunitpunct. The starred variant differs
> from the regular version in that it checks if the last \printtext,
> \printfield, \printlist, \printnames, or \bibstring command did
> actually print anything. If not, it does nothing.
>
> \printunit{⟨ punctuation⟩ } \printunit*{⟨ punctuation⟩ }
>
> The \printunit command is similar to \setunit except that
> ⟨punctuation⟩ persists in the buffer.
>
> This ensures that ⟨punctuation⟩ is inserted before the next non-empty
> field printed by the \printtext, \printfield, \printlist, \printnames,
> or \bibstring commands—regardless of any intermediate calls to
> \newunit or \setunit.

**Recommend** The punctuation tracker: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435164/161015