# Jumping point with biblatex \newunit

Tags: biblatex, bibliographystyle

Writing a new BibLaTeX bibliography style I noticed, I don't really understand how the puncuation algorithm of biblatex with `\newunit` (`\setunit{}`) and `\printXXX{}` works, if there is a `\newunit` before the first printed field. In the BibLaTeX documentation (4.7, 4.11.7 and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409148/what-do-setunit-and-newunit-do)) I found only explanations on the usage if a field in the middle of the bibliography driver is empty.

If the `\newunit` is before the first printed string, it does not print a point there (what I expected), but it does print one between the next two `\printXXX{}` even if there should be no punctuation there. The point is *jumping* from the begin to the next possible location.

See my MWE and the result:

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{WithTitle,
  title = {Testtext},
}

@article{WithoutTitle,
  title = {},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bbx}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit%
  \printtext{word}%
  \printtext{string}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=\jobname,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography

\cite{WithTitle}\cite{WithoutTitle}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of MWE]

What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I set a `\newunit` that does not jump?

Comment: imho as long as the newunit punctuation hasn't been used it will hang around and wait for its chance. Use \setunit{} after the first printtext to clear the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principles of the punctuation buffer and its workings are really rather simplistic. To understand why you get the result you get, the following should be sufficient (more details and examples can be found in the already linked [What do \setunit and \newunit do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409148/35864) and [biblatex: \DeclareCiteCommand adds semicolon between \printfield and \printnames, but only sometimes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435162/35864))

`\setunit{<punctuation>}` (for all intents and purposes `\newunit` is just `\setunit{\newunitpunct}`) puts `<punctuation>` into the punctuation buffer. If the buffer already contains a value, that value is overwritten (unless the previous value was added to the buffer with `\printunit`, `\printunit` persists in the buffer and cannot be overwritten).

The punctuation buffer is printed out and emptied whenever a `\printfield` (`\printlist`, `\printnames`, `\printtext`) prints something provided that anything has been printed at all (for `biblatex` punctuation is between two elements, so there is no point in printing punctuation before anything has been printed).

The current value remains in the buffer until it is overwritten by a `\setunit` or printed out between two `\print...` commands.

---

So now to

```
\printfield{title}%
\newunit%
\printtext{word}%
\printtext{string}%
\usebibmacro{finentry}%
```

If the `title` is non-empty, everything works as expected.

- `\printtext{title}` prints the title and tells the punctuation buffer that something was printed.
- `\newunit` puts `\newunitpunct` in the punctuation buffer.
- `\printtext{word}` prints the punctuation (and empties the buffer) and then "word".
- `\printtext{string}` prints "string".

Because the punctuation buffer is empty after `\printtext{word}`, there is no punctuation between "word" and "string".

If the `title` is empty, here is what happens.

- Nothing is printed by `\printtext{title}`.
- `\newunit` puts `\newunitpunct` in the punctuation buffer.
- `\printtext{word}` prints "word", but does not print any punctuation, because nothing was printed before. The buffer still contains `\newunitpunct`.
- `\printtext{string}` prints the punctuation, empties the buffer and then prints "string".

---

There are several ways to deal with the issue in this example, but depending on your actual use case some of these options might be preferable over others.

1. A simple solution is to move `\printtext{word}` and `\printtext{string}` into the same `\printtext{wordstring}`.
2. You could empty the punctuation buffer explicitly yourself with `\setunit{}` between `\printtext{word}` and `\printtext{strgin}` as suggested by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634455/jumping-point-with-biblatex-newunit#comment1581728_634455).
3. You can use the starred `\setunit*` instead of `\setunit`/`\newunit` after `\printfield{title}`, which only adds punctuation to the buffer if the previous command printed anything. (See [Is there any difference between \setunit*{<punct>} and \setunit{\add<punct>}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538920/35864) for a discussion of `\setunit` vs `\setunit*`.)

The following MWE shows these three ideas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit
  \printtext{wordstring}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit
  \printtext{word}%
  \setunit{}%
  \printtext{string}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{\newunitpunct}%
  \printtext{word}%
  \printtext{string}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{art:WithTitle,
  title   = {Testtext},
  presort = {a},
}
@article{art:WithoutTitle,
  title   = {},
  presort = {b},
}
@book{book:WithTitle,
  title   = {Testtext},
  presort = {c},
}
@book{book:WithoutTitle,
  title   = {},
  presort = {d},
}
@incollection{incoll:WithTitle,
  title   = {Testtext},
  presort = {e},
}
@incollection{incoll:WithoutTitle,
  title   = {},
  presort = {f},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] “Testtext”. wordstring. [2] wordstring. [3] Testtext. wordstring. [4] wordstring. [5] “Testtext”. wordstring. [6] wordstring.]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Know I understand the mechanism.