# \parencite{}, and extra semicolon

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a minor but annoying issue with \parencite{}, see screenshot below.

Here my MWE: .tex file

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[american,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,defernumbers=true,annotation=true,sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[style=apa,hyperref,sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}  % not better than above
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\author{myself}
\title{main bib}
\maketitle

\noindent
\nocite{*}

\defbibheading{Main}{\section{Main Section}}
\defbibnote{A}{nice books}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix={A-}]
\printbibliography[heading=Main, prenote={A}, keyword=A]

\end{document}
```

and .bib file

```
@Booklet{AAA,
author = {name surname},
label = {Ab},
title = {main title A, also as  \parencite{BBB},
pag.1-99, \parencite{CCC}, {\parencite{DDD}}, pp. 100-199},
howpublished = {Ok},
year = {2014},
location = {MyTown},
annotation = {also as  \parencite{BBB}, pag.1-99, \parencite{CCC}, {\parencite{DDD}}, pp. 1-99},
keywords = {A}
}

@Book{BBB,
author = {alpha beta},
title = {Main Book B},
publisher = {editor},
year = {2015},
keywords = {A}
}

@Book{CCC,
author = {aaa BBB},
title = {Main Book C},
publisher = {editor},
year = {2016},
keywords = {A}
}

@Book{DDD,
author = {{NML} {IJK}},
title = {Main Book D},
publisher = {editor},
year = {2017},
keywords = {A}
}
```

[image]

I do not get why/how I got those extra semicolons (;).  Any idea? Your help is welcome.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we had something like that before, let me search for it. The problem is that the punctuation tracker in the bibliography gets confused by a `\cite`. Ideally `\cite`s should be avoided in `.bib` entries.

Comment: @moewe "\cites should be avoided in .bib entries", really? It seems a pretty common situation, or I am missing a different command to get the same result?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397975/35864

Comment: I think that `\cite`s should be avoided in `.bib` entries, but then I'm only a mathematician and we usually have pretty straightforward references. Maybe what you want to do can be done with `related`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: thanks for the link/your help, it fixes it for my present job. Sorry I did not search better.

Comment: As usual it was much easier to find the answer if you knew what it was about. I'll close this question as a duplicate if you don't mind. But do look into `related`/`relatedtype`, maybe it can help you here.

Comment: fine to close, it is a duplicate!