# Biblatex-SBL special literature

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I am using biblatex-sbl and I have two problems with this style for my bibliography, though I have checked this file: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-sbl/biblatex-sbl-examples.pdf#page=22&zoom=100,0,714

1. but how to cite a publication within a series with a compund-name? As an example, there is the series "CSCO" with several sub-categories (such as "Subsidia"). I know that some scholars invent something like "CSCOSub.", and this can be a possibility:

   ```
   @mvbook{Voobus.1988,
    author = {V{\"o}{\"o}bus, Arthur},
    date = {1958/1988},
    title = {History of asceticism in the Syrian orient. A contribution to the history of culture in the Near East},
    location = {Louvain},
    volumes = {3},
   shorttitle = {History of asceticism},
   series = {Corpus scriptorum Christianorum Orientalium, Subsidia},
   shortseries = {CSCO.Sub},
   number = {184/197/500; 14/17/81*},
    keywords = {sekundaer},
    publisher = {Secr{\'e}tariat du Corpus SCO},
    isbn = {978-90-429-0541-2},
   }
   ```

Result:

> Vööbus, Arthur: History of asceticism in the Syrian orient. A
>   contribution to the history of culture in the Near East. 3 vols. CSCO
>   184.197.500, Subsidia 14.17.81, Louvain 1988.

But, I am wondering if it is possible to mention both series separate such as:

> Vööbus, Arthur: History of asceticism in the Syrian orient. A
>   contribution to the history of culture in the Near East. 3 vols. CSCO
>   184.197.500, Subsidia 14.17.81, Louvain 1988.

2. There is a two-volume book by a scholar. Only the second volume was reprinted and I was wondering how to mention this reference in the bibliography-file. Any hints?

Comment: Ideally questions on this site revolve only about one issue. It would make sense to split your two sub-questions into two separate questions. That way you don't scare away those who only know the answer to one part of the question, you also make your question more relevant for other people with similar issues.

Comment: A book with multiple series is possible. But it's a little tricky. See https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/issues/55

Comment: Also, your two outputs in your question look the same…

Comment: As for your second question, your could treat the two volumes as separate bibliography entries. This is acceptable in SBL style.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and desired output are not quite clear, but this might get you started.

The example output is taken from https://sblhs2.com/2017/03/02/separating-multiple-series/.

I'm not sure if things should be different for a sub-category as you've asked about here. But you could ask a question on the SBL Blog.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Voobus.1988,
  author = {Vööbus, Arthur},
  title = {History of Asceticism in the {Syrian Orient}},
  subtitle = {A Contribution to the History of Culture in the {Near East}},
  shorttitle = {History of Asceticism},
  volumes = {3},
  note = {\citeseries{CSCO} 184.197.500\ifbibliography{\addsemicolon}{\addcomma} Subsidia 14.17.81},
  location = {Louvain},
  publisher = {Secrétariat du Corpus SCO},
  date = {1958/1988}
}
@series{CSCO,
  series = {Corpus Scriptorum Christianorum Orientalium},
  shortseries = {CSCO},
  options = {skipbib}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{Voobus.1988}.
Filler text \autocite{Voobus.1988}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Output]

Comment: You probably know this, but I should probably warn other readers that `\cite` commands in the bibliography can sometimes have unwanted side-effects. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397975/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435162/35864 for example.

Comment: @moewe, yes! I think my `\citeseries` command is safer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I am wondering about the division between title and subtitle. Can you say how I can change the colon into a normal point between title and subtitle?

Comment: @anonym, SBL requires a colon. If you want to change it everywhere you can use `\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addperiod\space}`. Or to change it just for one entry, I would not use the `subtitle` field. Note too some other differences with capitalisation of titles.

Comment: @anonym, if a sub-series should be treated differently from a general multiple series case, it might make sense for me to add fields: `subseries`, `shortsubseries`, and `subnumber`. Or something like that. You could submit an issue at https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl

Comment: Another question to that: If you have a volume that is separated in a comment (in Roman numerals), together with a text edition and a translation (both in Arabic numerals and both starting with "1") - how can you specify your page numbers, e.g. : Vööbus, Arthur: History of asceticism in the Syrian orient. A contribution to the history of culture in the Near East. 3 vols. CSCO 184.197.500, Subsidia 14.17.81, Louvain 1988, 1 [syr. Text]; 4 [transl].

Comment: @anonym, please ask a new question and include an appropriate [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography). It makes it more useful for others to find. (And I'm about to go to bed, so you might get an answer sooner from others.)