# Weird semicolon between two citations

Tags: biblatex-chicago

In the following example, a weird semicolon appears between the two citations referenced from the third item in the bibliography:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,indexing=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@book{SambandhasivacharyaGanesan2010,
title = {\textsanskrit{Sūkṣmāgamaḥ} Vol.1, Chapters 1-13},
editor = {S. Sambandhaśivācārya and T. Ganesan},
publisher = {IFP/EFEO},
series = {Collection Indologie},
number = {114.1},
year =  {2010},
}

@book{SambandhanX2012,
title = {Sūkṣmāgama. Volume 2},
subtitle = {Chapters 14 to 53},
editor = {Sambandhaśivācārya, S. and Dagens, B. and Barazer-Billoret, M.-L. and Ganesan, T. and  Creisméas, J.-M.},
publisher = {Institut Français de Pondichéry},
series = {Steles: Jean Filliozat Series in South Asian Culture and History},
number = {3},
year = {2012},
}

@misc{SūkṣmāgamaBB,
title = {\textsanskrit{Sūkṣmāgama}},
note = {Voir \cite{SambandhasivacharyaGanesan2010} (Chapitres 1--13) et \cite{SambandhanX2012} (Chapitres 14--53)}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{french}
\nocite{SūkṣmāgamaBB}
\printbibliography
\end{french}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this a bug or a feature I don't understand?

Comment: it seems that the citation commands get confused, to find themselves inside a bibentry and insert a \multicitedelim punctuation. `\setunit{}\cite{SambandhanX2012}` could work, but you should also report it.

Comment: Using `\textcite` instead will get red of the semicolon. Try: `note = {Voir \textcite[Chapitres 1--13]{SambandhasivacharyaGanesan2010} et \textcite[Chapitres 14--53]{SambandhanX2012}}`

Comment: See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/988 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397975/35864.