Spurious space from biblatex strings
Consider the example
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\NewBibliographyString{extendedversionof}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    extendedversionof={extended version of}
}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\newbibmacro*{related:extendedversionof}[1]{\space\entrydata{#1}{\usefield\cite{clonesourcekey}}}
\begin{document}
    Test
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}

with example.bib:
@inproceedings{Proceedings,
    author={Me},
    title={A paper with an extended version},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the VIIth conference},
    year={1999}
}
@misc{Extended,
    author={Me},
    title={The extended version},
    year={2000},
    related={Proceedings},
    relatedtype={extendedversionof},
}

Which prints as

You see that there is a spurios space before the 1 in the citation [ 1] inside [2]. It disappears when one delets the bibliography string extendedversionof. The problem also appears when using the relatedstring-field instead. Where does this come from?

try with \renewcommand\relatedpunct{}.

try with \renewcommand\relatedpunct{}.

how does the relatedpunct get into the cite? In biblatex.def, I don't find any hint to that.

I didn't check, probably in one the bbx-files, or in biblatex.sty itself.

@Bubaya \cite commands in the bibliography have a tendency to come out with subtle punctuation issues, because the punctuation tracking can't deal with this "nested" situation properly. See for example https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/988, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397975/35864.
